# How to Store Matrix/Vector and values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to store vectors. When I run the program in the loop I see all the values, but when referred outside the loop only the last vector is evaluated and stored (the one that ends with prime number 953, see below). Any calculations done with the `PVX` vector are done only with the last entry. I want `PVX` to do calculations with all the results not just the last entry. How can I store these results to do calculations with?

This is the code:

```
PV=[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29];

for numba=2:n

    if mod(numba,PV)~=0;
        xp=numba;

     PVX=[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 xp]


    end
end
```

The first few results looks like this:

`PVX`: Prime Vectors (Result)

```
PVX =

     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    31

PVX =

     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    37

PVX =

     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    41

PVX =

     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    43


PVX =  ...........................................................


PVX =

     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    953
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store all `PVX` values, use a different row for each:

```
PV = [2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29];
PVX = [];
for numba=2:n
    if mod(numba,PV)~=0;
        xp = numba;
        PVX = [PVX; 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 xp];
    end
end
```

Of course if would be better to initiallize the `PVX` matrix to the appropriate size, but the number of rows is hard to predict.

---

Alternatively, build the `PVX` without loops:

```
xp = setdiff(primes(n), primes(29)).'; %'// all primes > 29 and <= n
PVX = [ repmat([2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29], numel(xp), 1) xp ];
```

---

As an example, for `n=100`, either of the above approaches gives

```
PVX =
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    31
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    37
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    41
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    43
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    47
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    53
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    59
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    61
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    67
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    71
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    73
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    79
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    83
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    89
     2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    97
```

Comment: WOW! this is what I am looking for Luis! and thanks to everyone again. but one question, which way is more efficient? My way that you modified(loop), or the one you did without the loop? thanks again! they seem to generate them just about the same time.

Comment: @Crisp Glad I could help. As a general rule in Matlab, [avoiding loops (vectorizing)](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) is always more efficient

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you were going for this:

```
PVX=[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29];

for numba=2:n

    if mod(numba,PVX)~=0;
        xp=numba;

        PVX(end+1) = xp;
        %// Or alternatively PVX = [PVX, xp];

    end
end
```

but if you could get an estimate of how large PVX will be in the end, you should pre-allocate the array first for a significant speed up.

Comment: yes i just saw that i forgot to put PV in there. thats right, I have made corrections.

Answer (score 2):

So, looks like you need all prime till `n`

As Dan said use this :

```
PVX=[2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 ];
for numba=2:n
    if mod(numba,PVX)~=0
        xp=numba;
        PVX=[ PVX xp];
    end
end
```

Or why not simply use [***`primes`***](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/primes.html) function ?

`PVX = primes( n ) ;`

Comment: no i want to create vectors with prime numbers from 2 to 29 and the 11th entry(last) will be any other prime number right up to whatever I choose to be n. so the number of vectors I want to have is the number of prime numbers from 31 to n. the first 10 entries will never change but the llth will. then store these vectors for calculations.

Comment: @Crisp I assume that you can do with `primes` too !